# rsync permission denied in www subfolder

Tags: linux, permissions, download, rsync, effective-permissions

I need to allow a specific user to download files from my web server.  The files will be in a specific directory and I don't want the downloader to read, write or do anything outside of that directory.  So, I created a regular user - let's call her Downloader - on a Debian 11 server.  I used the -d option to point that user's home directory to /var/www/example.com/Downloader

```
useradd -m -d /var/www/example.com/Downloader Downloader
```

All files in the example.com directory and below have permissions assigned as follows:

```
sudo chown -R WebAdmin /var/www/example.com/
sudo chgrp -R www-data /var/www/example.com/
sudo chmod -R 750 /var/www/example.com/
sudo chmod g+s /var/www/example.com/
```

and I further modified the Downloader directory as follows:

```
cd /var/www/example.com/Downloader
sudo chgrp -R Downloader ./
sudo chmod -R 750 ./
sudo chmod g+s ./
```

So now the permission look like this:

```
-rwxr-x---  1 WebAdmin Downloader         740 Apr 11 11:33 index.php
```

When I tried the command:

```
 rsync -arzvP Downloader@example.com:/var/www/example.com/Downloader/ ./
```

I get an error:

```
Could not chdir to home directory /var/www/example.com/Downloader/: Permission denied
receiving incremental file list
rsync: [sender] change_dir "/var/www/example.com/Downloader" failed: Permission denied (13)

sent 8 bytes  received 9 bytes  1.79 bytes/sec
total size is 0  speedup is 0.00
rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23) at main.c(1677) [Receiver=3.1.3]
rsync: [Receiver] write error: Broken pipe (32)
```

I understand that user Downloader cannot traverse the parent directories, /var/www etc. but I thought making the home directory the /var/www/example.com/Downloader would fix it.

BTW, I also tried

```
rsync -arzvP Downloader@example.com:/ ./
```

and it basically started downloading from the root folder (including the boot dev and other directories)!  I of course don't want that!

So, how do I achieve the desired result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's look at the permissions for the directory tree you've described:

```
sudo ls -ld /var /var/www /var/www/example.com /var/www/example.com/Downloader

drwxr-xr-x 13 root     root       4096 Sep 11  2022 /var
drwxr-xr-x  4 root     root       4096 Sep  8 10:27 /var/www
drwxr-s---  3 WebAdmin www-data   4096 Sep  8 10:26 /var/www/example.com
drwxr-s---  3 WebAdmin Downloader 4096 Sep  8 10:26 /var/www/example.com/Downloader
```

On inspection you can see that the permissions for `/var/www/example.com` prevent `Downloader` from being able to access its home directory, `/var/www/example.com/Downloader`.

We can verify this by becoming the `Downloader` user directly:

```
sudo -iu Downloader
sudo: unable to change directory to /var/www/example.com/Downloader: Permission denied
```

One solution is to relax the permissions on the parent directory so that `Downloader` can reach its destination. The minimum that will allow this is to give execute permissions to "others" (for a directory, execute permission means search permission):

```
sudo chmod o+x /var/www/example.com
```

And now when we reverify the situation it works as expected:

```
sudo -iu Downloader

pwd
/var/www/example.com/Downloader

id
uid=1009(Downloader) gid=1011(Downloader) groups=1011(Downloader)
```

However, none of this will address your primary statement, "*I don't want the downloader to read, write or do anything outside of that directory*". For that you would need to set up a `chroot` environment for the account and then the permissions structure becomes (much) more complicated. Right now, instead of `rsync -av Downloader@remoteHost:` (lists the files/directories on the remote because no destination path has been provided) they can also `rsync -av Downloader@remoteHost:/` and access everything on your remote server that isn't locked down.

Comment: Interesting.  rsync appears to work, and also prevents access to the parent of Downloader.  However, it appears that Downloader has a different shell (sh instead of bash).  I suppose it has nothing to with your solution, but how can I fix that?  Meanwhile, I am upvoting and accepting your answer.  Thanx!

Comment: The parent of Downloader is likely to be one of the few directories on the system that the Downloader account cannot access. But as `rsync` allows absolute paths after the colon the user can potentially access most other files/directories on your system. @Chiwda